# How to get transient highlighting to work from an elisp script?

Tags: emacs

I want an elisp script to highlight a region of text.
Upon exit, the highlighted selection should disappear when a key is pressed.
Everything I've tried results in the highlighting *hanging on* like the `shift` key is pressed. What does it need to make the selection *transient*?

```
(defun TEST ()
  (interactive)
  (transient-mark-mode t) ;; I have this true normally anyhow
  (set-mark (point))
  (forward-char 2)
  (setq mark-active t))
(global-set-key [C-S-f2] 'TEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in Emacs 24:

```
(setq transient-mark-mode t)

(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (push-mark (point))
  (forward-char 2)
  (activate-mark))
```

Comment: (one week later) On double-checking, it turns out that I asked the wrong question. I used the wrong terminology; "transient" means something different to what i thought... I finally resolved my issue via another related quesiton, when I realized that `C-x C-e` *evaluating* behaved differently from CUA mode, which in turn behaved differently from "non CUA" mode...  Here is the link for anyone intereted: [Different results when run different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337508/different-results-when-elisp-function-is-run-different-ways-why) ... Thanks for the help.